# Unexpected crash WCF Service on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

It will be long post, because I want to explain as mush as possible and detailed my problem. I'm new in backend developing and now I'm developing a secured (https) REST web service using WCF, C# and .NET Framework 4.5. For this case I use self-signed certificate, configured in IIS.
 My issue is that Service Host seems to crash randomly, without any exception or Message in Trace log. I tested it in VMware on Windows Server 2012 R2. On other operating systems (WS 2008, WS 2010) seems to work fine.
Here is how I start the service with registering EventHandler for Faulted state:

```
private ServiceHost listener = null;

public void Start(byte[] certData, string certPassword) {
    int port = Config.MobileServicePort;

    SslCertificate cert = new SslCertificate();

    cert.RemoveCertificate(port);
    cert.InstallCertificate(port, certData, certPassword);

    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://127.0.0.1:{0}/{1}", port, "MobileService"));

    if (listener != null) {
        listener.Close();
        listener = null;
    }

    listener = new ServiceHost(typeof(MobileService), uri);
    listener.Faulted += FaultedStateHandling;

    try {
        listener.Open();
        Logger.System().Info("REGISTER service at '{0}'", uri.ToString());
    } catch (TimeoutException timeEx) {
        Logger.System().Error("Open timeout exception: " + timeEx);
    } catch (CommunicationException comEx) {
        Logger.System().Error("Open communication exception: " + comEx);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.System().Error(ex);
    }
}
```

Here is Handler for Faulted state:

```
private void FaultedStateHandling(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        Logger.System().Info("<------------***Mobile service Faulted****------------>");
        listener.Abort();
        listener.Faulted -= new EventHandler(FaultedStateHandling);
        int port = Config.MobileServicePort;
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://127.0.0.1:{0}/{1}", port, "MobileService"));
        listener = new ServiceHost(typeof(MobileService), uri);
        listener.Faulted += new EventHandler(FaultedStateHandling);
        listener.Open();
        Logger.System().Info("<------------***Mobile service Restarted****------------>");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.System().Error(ex);
    }
}
```

This is my *app.config* configured for MessageLogging and Tracing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
     <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Critical,Information,ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\log\TraceMessages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>

       <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
         <listeners>
           <add name="messages"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="c:\log\MessageLogging.svclog" />
         </listeners>
      </source>

   </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging
          logEntireMessage="false"
          logMalformedMessages="true"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
          maxMessagesToLog="500"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="5000"/>
  </diagnostics>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MobileBehavior"     name="noq.Mobile.Service.MobileService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
                         bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" 
                         behaviorConfiguration="REST"
                         contract="noq.Mobile.Service.IMobileService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"  
              binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <!--<host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:11082/MobileService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>-->
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity" maxBufferSize="1000000000"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1000000000" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MobileBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
 </startup>
</configuration>
```

I stock with that issue for about 1 month and can't find a solution. I tried a lot of configurations, and it seems that problem is anywhere deeper. I checked the MSDN forum and support.microsoft. There I found similar issues but not the same, they offer some hot fixes, like [that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2726478). 
Is it possible that issue is associated to VM configuration? 
Thanks in advance and for any advice.

Comment: And what does the event log (either the Application log or System Log) tell you?

Comment: Hi, @rene, so in WCF Tracing I  found an error message like: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

Comment: @rene [hotfix from microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2537715) but only for WS2008R2. I tried to fix it by setting the BaseAddress in app.config file makes that this error doesn't appear anymore, but it doesn't resolve the issue service still crashing. I tried allmost all kind of configs for Service but still no results. In system log and application log - nothing, service just stops responding. From client side ( Android ), when service is down, in logs i see message: Unknown error during handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got a solution! And I spend too much time to resolve and diagnose such a stupid problem. Here is how I acted:

1. Run -> cmd -> eventvwr
2. Got a log message with errorcode 0x8009030D from source HttpEvent.
3. Applied this solution from [msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2012/10/07/error-hresult-0x80070520-when-adding-ssl-binding-in-iis/).

   Now the question is: which of this 3 Scenarios fixed my problem?
   And the second: How to apply this fixes programmatically?
   Good Luck!
   Arty